# syntax error in "SELECT DISTINCT _id near "SELECT"

Tags: android, sqlite

If someone knows a better way to get a rowId from text in the row, please let me know.

I've been running around in circles with this and I know it's probably something simple, but I can't figure it out.  Hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.  I'm getting an error running this SQLite code:

```
String where = "SELECT rowid, * FROM masterRecord WHERE masNameCol=" + name;
Cursor c =  db.query(true, masterName, ALL_KEYS_MASTER, where, null, null, null, null, null);
```

The error points to the second line.

"name" is a string variable (in this case it's "Mary").  The exact error I'm getting is:

SQLiteLog: (1) near "SELECT": syntax error in "SELECT DISTINCT _id, masNameCol, masTotalTimeCol FROM masterRecord WHERE SELECT rowid, * FROM masterRecord WHERE masNameCol=Mary"

I've tried every syntax change I could find and think of, and it never changes the error.  I'm just trying to get the rowId of the row so I can change a value in another column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rawQuery()`, not `query()`.

You are trying to specify the entire SQL statement, which is what `rawQuery()` is for. `query()` assembles the SQL statement from pieces, and your one piece (`where`) is not just the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This is very helpful.  Thank you.  Now I have a different error: no such column: Mary in "SELECT rowid, * FROM masterRecord WHERE masNameCol=Mary"  Using this now: Cursor c = db.rawQuery(where, null);  (where is still the same as above)

Comment: @swordguy8: In SQL, you need to quote string constants. Presumably, you want `SELECT rowid, * FROM masterRecord WHERE masNamCol='Mary'`.

Comment: Ok, I changed where to "SELECT rowid, * FROM  masterRecord WHERE masNameCol= ?"
Then changed rawQuery to rawQuery(where, new String[] {name})
and the error is gone!  But now I have an error in my return line.  I'm updating my original post to show that.

Comment: Didn't see your reply before figuring something out for the first issue.  Post is updated.

Comment: @swordguy8 don't change the requirement because this way you invalidate all the answers that you received. If the original problem is solved by one of the answers then accept it by clicking on its checkmark. If there is a new problem you can ask a new question. Take some time to read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399

Comment: I see.  Thank you for the etiquette tip.  Will do.  Oh, and thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholders for queries:

```
where = "masNameCol = ?";
whereArgs = new String[] { name };
columns = new String[] { "rowId" , /* all other column names you are interested in */  };
Cursor c =  db.query("mytable", columns, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
```